# Wait for Cypress to stop typing before timing out

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, cypress

I am trying to create a test to check performance speed by submitting 1000 entries.
**The Goal is** It shouldn't take more than 150000 ms to complete.

**Test:**

```
    it.only('should submit 1000 entries & should not take more then 150000ms', () => {
        let str = "";
        for (let round = 0; round < 10; round++) {
            for (let items = 0; items < 100; items++) {
                str += items + '{enter}';
            }
        }
        cy.get('[name="submitEntry"]', { timeout: 150000 }).type(str, { timeout: 150000 });
    });
```

**The Problem:**

When running the test it works for the first 35 seconds then it times out with CypressError "*Cypress command timeout of 33200ms exceeded.*" and it fails the test but continues to type.

I was trying to search for a way to wait until the typing is finished and all I found was using `{timeout:150000}` but it is not working in my case (and some other solutions which didn't work either).

While trying all sort of tweaks to try to get it to work I realized that it has something to do with string length since when I tried to change in the first `for` loop the `round < 10` to `round < 5` (which cuts the string in half) it timed out faster (at 18600ms).

Anyone has a clue what is going on here? & how I can get it to wait until it's done typing?